# Can't bind checkbox in partial view to the main model (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, partial-views, model-binding

I've been running into to issue and I've been searching for an answer but nothing helped.

I have a Model:

```
public class Filters
{
    public bool Filter1 { get; set; }
    public bool Filter2 { get; set; }
    public bool Filter3 { get; set; }
    etc...
}
```

I have a partial view with multiple checkboxes and tried multiple things:

```
<input id="Filter1" name="Filter1" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Filter1" />
```

and

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Filter1)
```

Then I have a main model:

```
public class Dashboard
{
    ...
    public Filters FiltersDashboard { get; set; }
}
```

And somewhere in the main view I insert the partial view like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FiltersDashboard, "Filters")
```

In a jquery, I execute an alert when the checkbox is clicked and shows the value of the checkbox. This value remains unchanged.

```
<script>
    $("#Filter1").click(function () {
        alert(" @Model.FiltersDashboard.Filter1 ")
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Also tried it in the .submit function but model value remains unchanged:

```
<script>
    $("#searchform").submit(function (event) {
        alert(" @Model.FiltersDashboard.Filter1 ")
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

This tells me that something isn't correctly bound but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Also, the reason I'm not using a checkboxlist is because I need to execute a different query for each filter so I need specific names and bindings for them.

Comment: alert(" @Model.FiltersDashboard.Filter1 ") will show the value of Filter1 of the model at the time of the view generation. The binding between the checkbox and the model will be done when the form is posted to the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have the partial view in the folder you've mentioned. Also does the 2nd parameter really matter in this case? The partial view loads correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't know this was the proper way to bind from a partial view. Thanks for the feedback. I will try to bind it like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Model.FiltersDashboard.Filter1` is razor code and is executed on the server before its sent to the view, so it will only ever return the initial value of the property (if you inspect the source code, you will see the initial value has been hard coded in your script).

However, if your script is being executed, then it means that you are using the manual `<input>` tags in your 2nd code snippet, in which case your view is not binding to your model because the correct `name` attribute would be `name="FiltersDashboard.Filter1"` and the associated `id` attribute would be `id="FiltersDashboard_Filter1"`.

Always use the strong typed `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` which will generate the correct html for 2-way model binding and client side validation.

Note also that it just needs to be `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FiltersDashboard)` - the 2nd parameter is unnecessary.

Then the script should be

```
<script>
    $('#FiltersDashboard_Filter1').click(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        alert(isChecked);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this mean that the only way to check the boolean value of the model is to pass the model to the post method in the controller and not in the script?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. The script I have shown will tell you if the checkbox is checked or not. But your model is server side code. The browser has no knowledge of it (it does not understand C# - its only programming language is javascript)